# Joomla Template Editing

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I'm using template at this [url](http://newjoomlatemplates.com/success) for my site. In page footer of my site, displays `Joomla! is Free Software released under the GNU General Public License.` phrase under the `Copyright © 2012 MySite. All Rights Reserved.` phrase . i need to remove `Joomla! is Free Software released under the GNU General Public License.` phrase. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your en-GB.mod_footer.ini file. Assuming you have Joomla installed in your site's root directory, the file is located at:

www.YOURSITE.com/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_footer.ini

Among other things, you'll see some code that looks like this:

```
FOOTER=Footer
FOOTER_LINE1=Copyright &#169; %date% %sitename%. All Rights Reserved.
FOOTER_LINE2=<a href="http://www.joomla.org">Joomla!</a> is Free Software released under the <a href="http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html">GNU/GPL License.</a>
MOD_FOOTER=<em>mod_footer</em>
THIS MODULE SHOWS THE JOOMLA! COPYRIGHT INFORMATION=This module shows the Joomla! copyright information.
```

Get rid of FOOTER_LINE2, then save the file and re-upload it to the /language/en-GB/ folder.

Good luck!

Cynthia

Comment: (Cynthia) It is worked. but now it displays `MOD_FOOTER_LINE2` instead of `Joomla! is Free Software released under the GNU General Public License.` how could i remove it ?

Comment: Try adding FOOTER_LINE2= back in but don't give it any value. If that doesn't work, go to your module manager and unpublish the copyright module THEN create a Custom HTML module that contains your relevant copyright info and publish it in the same module position that your original copyright module was published.

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with Joomla 1.5 and its move to Internationalization and full support of UTF-8, messages for footer.php and other Joomla pages has been moved to a language specific file.
>   **If you want to change the text, go to the language directory, go to the folder of the language you want to change, find the mod_footer.ini file and change the relevant text. For British English, the specific file is language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_footer.ini.** Remember that you may not remove copyright and license information from the source code.
>   If you want to remove the footer entirely, go to Extensions > Module Manager and unpublish the footer module.
>   Other places where can look for options to make changes are these. If you find code related to footers in these files, you can either "comment it out" or remove it:
>   /includes/footer.php file.
>   index.php file for your active template

Source: http://docs.joomla.org/Can_you_remove_the_%22Powered_by_Joomla!%22_message%3F

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit the following for the Admin page, `<InstallationFolder>/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.ini` line 332:

```
JGLOBAL_ISFREESOFTWARE="%s is free software released under the <a href="_QQ_"http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html"_QQ_">GNU General Public License</a>."
```